# How to set internal vim variable from python code

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to write vim plugin for easier work with cmake. I want it to read some values from json file: build_dir, generator, cmake VARS and then give vim user few functions: configure, build, maybe run.

I decided to use python, because it's easy to run cmake from it and easy to parse json.
But i have problem with understanding where i need to save values from json.

I decided to just save them to vim variables, `g:cmake_configuration_name` for example. But i didn't find way to do this. I read help python few times already and tried to google it, no luck.

Maybe that's just bad way to do this, so i need help with this too.

Comment: Try asking in [vim exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: oh, sorry
didn't know about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this from code running in an external interpreter but you can do it from within `vim` using builtin [`:python[3]`](https://vimhelp.org/if_pyth.txt.html#if_pyth.txt) command. Example:

```
:py3 import vim
:py3 vim.command("let g:my_test_var = 'my test value'")
:py3 vim.command("echo g:my_test_var")
my test value
```